# How to preview documents in SalesForce?

Tags: visualforce, api, libraries, document

In my Apex page we want to show the preview for the SalesForce documents?

We want to have preview for the following file types?

Supported file types:

MSWord, MSExcel, PDF and PPT.

Is the any we can use SF visual components or API to achieve this.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you trying to "preview" as Salesforce does wherein you have a popup with the preview?  Or are you simply trying to display a document within a visualforce page?

Comment: I just want to preview the document so whichever is feasible I'm good with that. Now i can able to preview the PDF files but it occupies the entire screen. So preview as a popup or VisualForce page with headers is good.

Comment: Have you investigated Accusoft's document viewer for salesforce?

Comment: Anyone got answer for this?

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few "document previewers" out there.

The one I would use is this the google docs viewer.   You can use the link below to get the URL format you'd need for the file, and then I'd embed that in a visualforce page using `<apex:iframe>`

https://docs.google.com/viewer

Other options include flexpaper or issu

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/default.jsp
http://issuu.com

Another easier option which works well is to just use a simple embed tag with src= url of your file which if its an attachment can use the following syntax

```
<embed src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, worksheet.Attachments[0].Id)}" style="width:100%; height:950px;">
 </embed>
```

Comment: That is possible for normal documents but is it possible to view the documents that has been published under SalesForce library using google docs viewer?

Comment: Hmm well those files are only viewable internally so google can see them but for those i'd used a simple embed tag eg. <embed src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, worksheet.Attachments[0].Id)}" style="width:100%; height:950px;">
                </embed>

Comment: It' Perfectly working for pdf files. But the docx files got downloaded instead of showing preview.

Comment: Hmm yea thats going to be harder with the Microsoft file formats.  The only real solutions i've found for those are the google docs view or the office 365 viewer but both of those require the documents to have a publicly accessible URL.  If thats not possible then you may have to use a flash based option like flexpaper (http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/demo/) i haven't used it personally but i think it will do what you need?  You can see a similar question chain here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558936/embedding-ms-word-documents-in-html

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the cool native Sales force document preview feature and are trying to use it in a custom Visualforce page?

I think to the best of my knowledge, there is no direct way to do this.

Please see:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Y1QLAA0

This person had a solution to this. The link seems to be down for now. I hope its a temporary issue. 
http://softwarecycling.com/post/10847679195/salesforce-showfilepreview

Comment: The link seem to be down in 2017